# What's the meaning of `unless -d`?

Tags: perl

Reading the code,I find this:

```
use File::Path;
mkpath($hinitdir) unless -d $hinitdir;
mkpath($hrestdir) unless -d $hrestdir;
```

So what's the meaning of the option `-d`?

Comment: See the documentation for file test operators [-X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) : `-d  File is a directory`

Comment: Note that `mkpath` already skips trying to create existing directories, so `mkpath($hinitdir) unless -d $hinitdir;` should simply be `mkpath($hinitdir);`

Comment: @ikegami yeah,concise is beauty.Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has "file test" operators of the form `-X`, where the letter after the dash tells Perl what you want to test. These are documented in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) collectively under [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#-X-FILEHANDLE).

The `-d` tests that the target (in this case `$hinitdir` or `$hrestdir`) is a directory. The target of a file test operator can be either a named file of a file handle.

Apart from that, recent [File::Path](http://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Path) versions use `make_path` over the old `mkpath`.